# A strange hotel

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, story

Entering the lobby, I requested a room. The clerk handed me my key and I took the elevator to my floor. To my surprise there was a sign on the door of my room telling me I should try a different room instead.

I headed to my new room on the floor above. But I simply couldn't find the door. I looked to the room next to where it should be, but a burly looking security guard said I wasn't allowed in there.

So I took the elevator a floor higher where the restaurant was located. No sooner had I arrived when one of the waitstaff clumsily spilled a drink over me!

I stormed back to the lobby and made my concerns known. The response from the front desk clerk was that there was only really one room in this hotel which was OK.

Which room number should I try?

Comment: Did the sign say to try any different room or did it say to try a specific room?

Comment: Does this hotel have anything to do with a rot13(zrgebvqinavn)

Comment: I hope you aren't in Hotel California :). Anyway, thanks for the puzzle, and welcome to Puzzling.SE! I removed the "riddle" tag and replaced it with "story" since this isn't quite a "riddle".

Comment: @cstafford-14 a specific room

Comment: @bewilderer no afraid not

Answer (score 120, accepted):

All the rooms in this hotel correspond to

> [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) and their corresponding message phrases.
>
>  You began on third floor, likely in front of room 307 where you were **[307 REDIRECTED](https://httpstatuses.com/307)** to the fourth floor. There you got to room 404 which was **[404 NOT FOUND](https://httpstatuses.com/404)**. Next to it was room 403, which was **[403 FORBIDDEN](https://httpstatuses.com/403)**. At the restaurant, the server spilled a drink on you because of a [500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR](https://httpstatuses.com/500) (*thanks, El-Guest*)!
>
>  Your real room number is 200, because that is [200 OK](https://httpstatuses.com/200).

Comment: Note that the restaurant was in room 500, and the spill was because there was an rot13(vagreany freire reebe)!

Comment: Very good! I'm glad I didn't go to room 418.

Comment: And now you're in Room 212 ;)

Comment: I would have left and dos'd the hotel with an army of bots.

Comment: I (lterally) couldn't find 212.

Comment: That's very clever, I wouldn't have considered status codes at all.

Comment: There's a 212 *FTP Return Code* `212 - Directory Status` - But not an HTTP Status Code

Comment: Room 201 is currently under construction and room 202 seems to be laundry. 204 have a lack of furniture.

Comment: I think I know this hotel. I stumbled into the Rule 34 suite by mistake. It took seven security guards to pull me out.